# Intl DateTimeFormat.format and Date.toLocaleString output different results

Tags: javascript, date, internationalization

I'm not sure where this is defined, but if I have a Date object and want to convert to string using a specific locale, I can use the extensions "toLocaleString", "toLocaleDateString" and/or "toLocaleTimeString".

Those are working fine, but [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Performance) that for a large number of items that could be a problem (I believe because the extension methods may be creating a new DateTimeFormat object for each date).

So, I followed the advice there and created a new DateTimeFormat and try to format my dates with the format method.

My issue with that is that the format method seems to format the date as "only date" (no time), and there is no way I can specify it otherwise but by passing an options object to the DateTimeFormat ctor... But that implies that I want a specific format, which is not the case (because I don't want to have my own db of locale formats)... I want the default format for those dates as if I were calling toLocaleString/toLocaleDateString/toLocaleTimeString.

Is there any way I can obtain the default formattings for each of those options? I would like to have to be able to format my DateTimes/Dates/Times using the default formatting for the specific locale.

I know I will need 3 DateTimeFormat objects (one for the full date/time, one for the date and another for the time), but that's ok if I can pass to each one the correct initialization object.

Comment: What do you mean by "*default format for those dates*"? If you mean those provided by the built-in *toLocaleString*, then that is implementation dependent and does not necessarily match the host preferences for date format (e.g. Chrome). There is no reliable way to determine the host date format settings, it's been an issue for 20 years and despite all the sugar added to ECMAScript in the meantime, built-in Date parsing and formatting is as useless as ever.

Comment: BTW, formatting a date for each location isn't internationalisation, it's localisation. This tag seems to acknowledge that in it's description: "*…the process of planning and implementing products and services so that they can easily be adapted to specific local languages and cultures, a process called localization.*". Internationalisation should use one format that is understood everywhere, which is much easier to achieve.

Comment: I don't need the "host" date format per se. I need the format(s) that belongs to a specified locale. For each locale the host has an internal definition on how a date/number should be displayed for a specific locale.

Comment: Also, you got wrong what internationalization is. Internationalization is translation + localization. It's not easier, but harder if not planned correctly. Text length for example is quite hard to plan in advance.

Comment: The "locale" in the Intl object is expressed as a language code, so not really a locale. My approach to dates is to use an unambiguous format, since where a person is located does not necessarily determine the format they wish to see. Using an unambiguous format at least means everyone will correctly interpret the date.